# How to access a part of an element from a list?

Tags: python, excel, list, data-science, scrape

```
import cv2
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
from pylibdmtx import pylibdmtx
import xlsxwriter


# co de for scanning

img_dir = "C:\\images" # Enter Directory of all images
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files = glob.glob(data_path)
data = []
result=[]

for f1 in files:
    img = cv2.imread(f1,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    msg = pylibdmtx.decode(thresh)
    print(msg)
    data.append(img)
    result.append(msg)

print(type(result[0]))
```

I have a lsit of 4 list inside a lists names result .The output of above code is result . The code is intended to read the barcode , but it also provides location which is not required by me .

SO after the above code , I have a output named result , whch gives me ::

```
[[Decoded(data=b'AZ:HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY', rect=Rect(left=37, top=152, width=94, height=97))], [Decoded(data=b'AZ:RCHKBW5WGZE98J7E9853OW4ZHE', rect=Rect(left=40, top=125, width=91, height=95))], [Decoded(data=b'AZ:5Z7HME1FRNAZFINDPTDAOTB9GQ', rect=Rect(left=27, top=112, width=88, height=88))]
```

so NOW i want ot jsut extract or find The az aprt from the all the single lists and export it to excel.

```
AZ:HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY
AZ:RCHKBW5WGZE98J7E9853OW4ZHE
AZ:5Z7HME1FRNAZFINDPTDAOTB9GQ
```

I want only the above output and omit all the location details .

I have tried with indexing , but IT's saying lists out of range.

Please helpme.

Comment: What have you tried ? What are the object inside the list, is that a class of yours ?

Comment: Actually these are the outputs after scanning some codes , now I want only the result part , not location or any stuff , I only want AZ part from all 4 lists and export it to excel

Comment: I get it, but what is the type of object inside the list ? Could you please share `print(type(mylist[0]))` and the code that built the list if you have it. We need to understand what type of element is inside the list to understand how to access its properties

Comment: print(type(result[0]))
<class 'list'>

Comment: Don't post links to off-site code (which may eventually disappear).

Comment: I was able to paste the code here , please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate on the list and retrieve the good properties on each.

```
values = [[Decoded(data=b'AZ:HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY', rect=Rect(left=37, top=152, width=94, height=97))],
          [Decoded(data=b'AZ:9475EFWZCNARPEJEZEMXDFHIBI', rect=Rect(left=32, top=191, width=90, height=88))],
          [Decoded(data=b'AZ:6ECWZUQGEJCR5EZXDH9URCN53M', rect=Rect(left=48, top=183, width=88, height=89))],
          [Decoded(data=b'AZ:XZ9P6KTDGREM5KIXUO9IHCTKAQ', rect=Rect(left=73, top=121, width=91, height=94))]]

datas = [value[0].data for value in values]          # list of encoded string (b'')
datas = [value[0].data.decode() for value in values] # list of strings
```

Comment: IT's not working , Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'    getting error

Comment: @KriteshLunawat so you have a list of 4 elements, and each element is a list of one element ? Try the new code

Comment: I have pasted the code here , please help me now , I have tried what you suggested above , but    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <listcomp>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'  error

Comment: @KriteshLunawat i don’t get it. Share exactly the output of print(result)

Comment: In have edited the question , I hope you are able to understand now

Comment: @KriteshLunawat have you jsut tried the new code I posted yesterday ? using `value[0]` ?